# How to stream audio file from another domain using jquery ajax avoiding crossdomain policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a web audio player like SoundCloud footer player using jQuery and HTML5 audio tag. The only-one problem is how to stream an audio file from another domain? (This player plugin could be installed in any website with some basic setup in JSON).

This is the console response when trying to stream an audio file:

[image: Console response]

The expected answers should be in jQuery.

Update: I've tried to use 'crossdomain' html5 attribute and crossDomain property in jQuery.ajax() but no effect.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple routes...

Firstly, if you're not reading that audio data or doing anything client-side with that audio, you can just use `<audio src="..." />` as normal.  CORS doesn't come into play until you're actually trying to use script to read that audio.  If you're using some sort of special player code... don't.  Just use a normal HTML5 `<audio>` tag or the `Audio` class.

Next, if you do *need to read the raw audio data*, either direct from the URL or to record/process the resulting decoded audio, your server must be configured to allow for CORS for this resource.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers is the easiest way to get there, but you should read up on CORS and understand it before proceeding so that you don't accidentally make something insecure on that server.

Comment: I used ajax to retrieve the audio stream and it works. But when I tried to set the audio link to <audio src="...">, it says that it's been disallowed (as above in the image)

Comment: @nael_d Yeah, so don't use AJAX to retrieve the audio stream.

Comment: okay got it. But please could you tell me how to avoid (or fix) CORS issue? How to make <audio> play the song from outside my website domain? This is my issue.

Comment: @nael_d I did... I gave you two ways.  One, don't use AJAX.  Two, put the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in the response.

Comment: Any online jsfiddle examples please? Really thank you Sir.

Comment: @nael_d Examples for what?  I gave you the one code example in my answer.  It's really that simple.  What are you getting confused about?

Comment: In fact, I'm getting confused about (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) itself. I've read lot of articles in mozilla developers but I didn't get it clearly. :-(

Comment: @nael_d Post a new question, asking about how to enable CORS for your particular webserver.  (Undoubtedly it will be closed as a duplicate, because this question comes up every day.)